# Why am I getting incorrect response from my chatbot (ChatterBot)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chatbot, chatterbot

When I ask for **"Contact Details"**, the chatbot replies for **"Admission Details"**.

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Python code:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
import spacy

spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from chatterbot import languages
languages.ENG.ISO_639_1 = "en_core_web_sm"

chatbot = ChatBot('WISO', storage_adapter = 'chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter', 
        logic_adapters=[
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
            'default_response': "Hi! I am WISO. How can I help you today? <br> <button>About</button> <br> <button>Courses  </button> <br><button> Admission Details</button><br> <button>Placements</button><br> <button> Student Life </button><br> <button>Events</button> <br> <button>Contact Details</button>",
            'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.90
        }
        ],
        database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3')
```

This is my Knowledge Base:

```
conversation = [
.
.
.
"Admission Details",
"<br><button>Detail Enquiry Form </button><br><button>Admission Process</button>",
.
.
.
"Contact Details",
"<b>Call us on:</b> 1234567890<br> <br><b>Address:</b> abcdzyxlmonpq"
]
```

Training:

```
list_trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)
corpus_trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

list_trainer.train(conversation)
corpus_trainer.train('chatterbot.corpus.english.greetings')
```